# remove the last character and multiply the value with a number using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am using dstat tool to get the network usage of eth0 interface.
dstat gives the output as below:

```
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- --net/eth0- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw
  3   2  95   1   0   0|4035B  143k|   0     0 |   0     0 |1539  2511
  3   3  94   0   0   0|   0    24k|3924B 7549B|   0     0 |1821  2851
  3   3  94   0   0   0|   0    84k|3766B 2648B|   0     0 |1787  2895
```

I am able to get the values of **--net/eth0-** in a seperate file. But I want to use **3924B** value and remove the last character **B/K/M**. And multiply the remaining number with 1024 if its **K** and multiply with 1024*1024 if its **M** using awk.
e.g if its 37K: I want 37888 (37*1024).

So far I am able to get the values in another file using below code:

```
dstat $Intrfc $Intrvl $repNo | sed '1,2d' | awk -F '|' '{print $3 }' | awk '{print $1 "," $2}' | sed "s/^/`date +%m:%d:%Y:%H:%M:%S`,/" >> $outFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.  As requested, it will multiply `K` numbers by 1024 and `M` numbers by 1048576.  It requires GNU `awk`:

```
dstat $Intrfc $Intrvl $repNo | awk -F '[| ]+' -v d=$(date +%m:%d:%Y:%H:%M:%S) -v OFS=, 'function cvt(x){return lshift(x, 10*(x~/K/)+20*(x~/M/))} NR>2 {print d,cvt($10),cvt($11)}'
```

#### Explanation

- `-F '[| \t]+'`

This sets the field separator to any combination of whitespaces and/or vertical bars.  With this field separator, the net/eth0 `recv` is field 10 and the `writ` is field 11.

- `-v d=$(date +%m:%d:%Y:%H:%M:%S)`

  This creates an `awk` variable `d` and assigns it to the output of your `date` command.
- `-v OFS=,`

  This sets the output field separator to a comma.
- `function cvt(x){return lshift(x, 10*(x~/K/)+20*(x~/M/))}`

  This creates a conversion function that multiplies by 1024 if the number ends in `K` and by 1048576 if the number ends in `M`.

  The multiplication is performed by left-shifting the number by 10 or 20 bits for K or M, respectively.

  Note that this function makes use of awk's loose typing.
- `NR>2 {print d,cvt($10),cvt($11)}`

  This prints the output.  `NR` is the line number.  The first two lines are skipped,  For all later lines (`NR>2`), the date is printed, followed by the converted column 10 and the converted column 11.

Comment: I would suggest you do not use old and outdated back-tick, use parentheses like this: `-v d=$(date +%m:%d:%Y:%H:%M:%S)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `0` in `awk`to get rid of the `B` etc

```
dstat $Intrfc $Intrvl $repNo awk -F\| 'NR>2 {split($3,a," ");print a[1]+0","a[2]+0}'
0,0
3924,7549
3766,2648
```

With math:

```
awk -F\| 'NR>2 {split($3,a," ");a[1]*=(a[1]~/K$/?1024:1);a[1]*=(a[1]~/M$/?1048576:1);a[2]*=(a[2]~/K$/?1024:1);a[2]*=(a[2]~/M$/?1048576:1);print a[1]","a[2]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

At first do not use multiple `awk`s and `sed`s in a pipe snake. It can be done in one step by one `awk`. Here is a possible solution:

```
awk -F"[ \t|]+" -v dt=$(date +%m:%d:%Y:%H:%M:%S) '
function num(n) {
  if (n ~ "B$") n=substr(n,1,length(n)-1);
  else if (n ~ "K$") n=substr(n,1,length(n)-1)*1024;
  else if (n ~ "M$") n=substr(n,1,length(n)-1)*1024*1024;
  return n;
}
NR>2{print num($10)","num($11)","dt}
' <<TXT
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- --net/eth0- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw
  3   2  95   1   0   0|4035B  143k|   0     0 |   0     0 |1539  2511
  3   3  94   0   0   0|   0    24k|3924K 7549B|   0     0 |1821  2851
  3   3  94   0   0   0|   0    84k|3766M 2648B|   0     0 |1787  2895 
TXT
```

Output:

```
0,0,01:07:2015:09:32:24
4018176,7549,01:07:2015:09:32:24
3.94894e+09,2648,01:07:2015:09:32:24
```

A little bit shorter version with better output for bigger numbers (I borrowed the multiplication idea from John1024):

```
awk -F"[ \t|]+" -v dt=$(date +%m:%d:%Y:%H:%M:%S) '
function num(n) {
  m="";
  if (n~"[^0-9]$") {m=substr(n,length(n),1);n=substr(n,1,length(n)-1);}
  return n * 2**(m=="K"?10:m=="M"?20:0);
}
NR>2{printf("%d,%d,%s\n", num($10),num($11),dt)}
'
```

Output:

```
0,0,01:07:2015:09:30:27
4018176,7549,01:07:2015:09:30:27
3948937216,2648,01:07:2015:09:30:27
```

In the example I used here-doc instead of pipeing `dstat` as I do not have dstat installed.

I hope this can help.